# Text indents on h1 and h3 tags and I can't remove it

Tags: html, css, text, format, dreamweaver

I don't remember changing any CSS styles or code that would affect the h1 and h3 tag, however it now indents while the paragraph tag does not. I've tried looking all throughout my code and I am not able to fix it! I want all the text to align left like my paragraph text does. Here is a link to a page where you can see the issue: http://ukneurology.com/html/clinicInfo/stroke.html

Comment: Here is my question: I have had that class in my html code since I built the site about a month ago and it worked fine. That class keeps the text in the side bar from bumping against the edge and it hasn't effected any of my other text ever until today. Because that class includes #right-sidebar, shouldn't it only effect the text in the sidebar? Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: The problem is not the class but the h1-h6 contained in the rule, just remove them (or just h1 and h3) and you'll be fine

Answer (score 3):

You have padding-left set on all you header tags

```css
.container .bgdImage #right-sidebar p, h1, h2, h3, h3, h5, h6 {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the source of `stroke.html` you have the following CSS:

```css
.container .bgdImage #right-sidebar p, h1, h2, h3, h3, h5, h6 {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

You're setting the `padding-left` to `40px` here.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container .bgdImage #right-sidebar p, h1, h2, h3, h3, h5, h6 {
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Use this instead of your previous class.